# Can I append several child divs with an onclick taking different parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I think I can explain this properly. I have a function that I want to call with an onclick event on several divs.

```
$scope.dataArray = [];  //array for holding values from another function

$scope.myFunction = function(id) {
    var val1 = id[0];
    var val2 = id[1];
}
```

And I want to assign this function to an onclick on divs that I append to a parent inside this function.

```
$scope.appendDivs = function (someData) {
    var result = someData;  // an array
    var parentContainer = document.getElementById('parent-container');
    for( var i = 0; i < result.length; i++)
    {
       var div = document.createElement('div');
       div.className = "child-element";
       parentContainer.appendChild(div);
       div.onclick = function() {
          $scope.myFunction(result.id);  //pass an array of data to myFunction
       };
       div.innerHTML = result[i].data1 + "<br>" + result[i].data2;
}
```

The problem lies in when I click the div to activate the onclick call and I debug to see what's going on, $scope.myFunction always gets passed the length of "result" where nothing is defined at. i.e. a length of 3 has elements 0, 1 and 2. myFunction tries to look at results[3].  Is there a way I can have each div know which element to pass to myFunction?

Comment: Where are you using/reading the length/index?

Comment: It looks like you are using angular... under that assumption, why not take advantage of angular directives? Specifically `ng-repeat` and `ng-click`. Here is a good angular example you might be able to follow to better achieve the functionality you are attempting here http://curran.github.io/screencasts/introToAngular/exampleViewer/#/17

Comment: $scope.myFunction just creates two local variables not visible elsewhere. Do you have any other code in that method that uses the variables?

Comment: I keep forgetting about ng-click, but the problem is still with "i" being read as my length each time onclick is called. However, I was able to get around my problem by piggybacking my value onto div.id. I don't need the id of the div for anything, and I was able to get rid of the dataArray as well. So now I can just pass the value I need into myFunction and it's the corresponding value to the div that is clicked. Thanks for your time though guys!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around my problem by piggybacking my value onto div.id. I don't need the id of the div for anything, and I was able to get rid of the dataArray as well. So now I can just pass the value I need into myFunction and it's the corresponding value to the div that is clicked. Thanks for your time though guys!